# How to prevent a middleware for a specific route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a middleware, which checks to admin logged in or not. And it's works for all `/admin` routes.

But I have a route for admin logins and it has a route like this: `/admin/login`. That's why login page is not opening. I want to prevent that middleware on this specific route. How can I do this?

These are my routes:

```
app.use('/', favoriteBlogsMW, indexGetRoutes, indexPostRoutes)
app.use('/admin', adminAuthMW, adminGetRoutes, adminPostRoutes)
```

Here is login page route, which I want to prevent middleware for in adminGetRoutes.

```
//this route works like this: /admin/login
router.get('/login', (req, res) => {
    
    if(req.cookies.jwt){
        res.redirect('/admin')
    } else {
        res.render('admin/login')
    }

})
```

Comment: You could try something like this `app.use(/\/admin(?:/(?!login).*)?/`. Express routes support regular expressions and this is a negative lookahead.

Comment: Maybe create subapp for `/admin/*` routes and process them by their set of middleware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set the middleware *after* defining the `/login` route.

Create a separate file that contains all the routes and export `Router` from this file.

```
// adminRoutes.js
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

// define "/login" route
router.get('/login', (req, res) => { ... });

// add the middleware
router.use(adminAuthMW);

// define the routes that need the "adminAuthMW" middleware
router.post(...)
router.get(...)
...

module.exports.adminRouter = router;
```

And in the main file,

Change

```
app.use('/admin', adminAuthMW, adminGetRoutes, adminPostRoutes)
```

to

```
app.use('/admin', adminRouter);
```

Answer (score -3):

You could do it inline as well. I prefer it that way. like this on the server:

```
app.use('/admin', require('../login'))
```

And the route file like this:

```
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('login', {title: 'User', user})
}
```

Answer (score -4):

> you can use res.redirect() method/function instead of res.render()
>
> res.render() => It only renders the views and doesn't redirect the
> routes

code:

```
router.get('/login', (req, res) => {
    
    if(req.cookies.jwt){
        res.redirect('/admin')
    } else {
        res.redirect('/admin/login')
    }

})
```

Comment: /login route is in adminGetRoute file. So, that means it works /admin/login. That's why your code not works.